# Oracle - Replacing all characters to “X”, except last 4 character

Tags: oracle

I try to find out the solution here but no luck, so I try to raise a question here see who can help me for this.

Refer to the topic, I would like to replacing all characters to “X”, except last 4 characters or less for a Oracle column.

For example:

1. 123456789 will become XXXXX6789 (First 5 character change to X)
2. 12345678 will become XXXX5678 (First 4 character change to X)
3. 1234567 will become XXX4567 (First 3 character change to X)
4. 123456 will become XX3456 (First 2 character change to X)
5. 12345 will become X2345 (First character change to X)
6. 1234 will become 1234 (remain no change)
7. 123 will become 123 (remain no change)
8. 12 will become 12 (remain no change)
9. 1 will become 1 (remain no change)

I try to used below statement but seem not work for case 8 and 9.

1) Return nothing instead of '1'.

```
Select RPAD('X',length('1')-4,'X') || substr('1',length('1')-4,length('1')) from dual
```

2) Return '2' instead of '12'.

```
Select RPAD('X',length('12')-4,'X') || substr('12',length('12')-4,length('12')) from dual
```

I try to used another statement below, however it return 'XX67XX' instead of 'XX6745'.

I guess there are repeated digits cause it return invalid value.

```
select REPLACE('456745', substr('456745',1,length('456745')-4), RPAD('*',length('456745')-4,'X')) From dual
```

Perhaps anyone can help?

Thank in advance.

Comment: if this is an application security requirement, our redaction policy feature allows this regex to be applied to a column so no code in the application layer requires changing - just query your number, and it comes redacted out of the database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this will work for longer strings :

```
LPAD(SUBSTR('123456789',-4),LENGTH('123456789'),'X')
```

I would wrap this in a CASE statement

```
CASE
  WHEN LENGTH(<your string>) > 4 
   THEN LPAD(SUBSTR(<your string>,-4),LENGTH(<your string>),'X')
  ELSE <your string>
END
```

Some other people will post beautiful regular expression answers which fascinate me because I can read them but cannot produce them

Comment: haha, I expected a regex-answer, but this case when statement is much simpler to understand and eventually even more efficient

Comment: Thank your help. Im manage apply your example to my project.
Very appreciate your help.